# Angular $http PUT data not being received by Laravel 4 when using 'multipart/form-data'

Tags: ajax, rest, angularjs, laravel-4

Hallo :) I'm using a RESTful API built in Laravel 4 combined with Angular for heavy-lifting on the frontend.

The intention is to be able to create a new 'item' in the database by POSTing form data to an API (including a file). A user can also edit an item using PUT/PATCH in the same way.

For whatever reason, I can POST data (using $http) and that works fine, but if I use PUT, no data is received by Laravel. I've also tried PATCH. The data is definitely sent by $http as you can see here: [http://paste.laravel.com/1alX/raw](http://paste.laravel.com/1alX)

I can tell that Laravel isn't getting/processing any data by echoing out the $input variable.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with Angular not sending data in the right way, or an Issue with Laravel not receiving/processing it correctly.

**The Javascript (Somewhat simplified):**

```
var formdata = new FormData();
// Unfortunately we cant just walk through the data with a FOR because the data is an object, not an array – We have to be explicit
// If data exists THEN add data to FormData ELSE do nothing
formdata.append('title', $scope.item.title);
formdata.append('description', $scope.item.description);
formdata.append('image', $scope.item.image);
formdata.append('tags', $scope.item.tags);
formdata.append('priority', $scope.item.priority);


edititem: function(formdata) {
    // Edits a particular list
    // id: the ID of the list to edit
    // data: the edited list object
    var promise = $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: 'http://mamp.local/api/v1/items/64',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            data: formdata,
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            debug(data, 'API FAIL - edit item');
            return data;
        })
        .success(function(response){
            debug(response.data, 'API Success - edit item');
            return response.data;
        });

    return promise;
},
```

**The PHP:**

```
/**
* Update the specified resource in storage.
*
* @param  int  $id
* @return Response
*/
public function update($id)
{
    // Try and store the new List
    $item = $this->itemRepo->updateitem($id, $this->user, Input::all());

    // Lets check if we have any validation errors
    if (count($item->errors()))
    {
        return Response::json(['errors' => $item->errors()->all()], 400);
    }
    // No errors
    else
    {
        return Response::json(['id' => $item->id], 200);
    }
}


/**
* Updates the item
*
* @param int $id the item ID
* @param User $user
* @param array $input
*
* @return item the item
*/
public function updateitem($id, User $user, $input)
{
    // Grab the item
    $item = $this->finditem($id, $user);

    // Fill item with new input
    $item->fill($input);

    // Do we have an image?
    if (Input::hasFile('image'))
    {
        // Handle resizing of the image
        $item->image = $this->imageManipulator->resize($this->imageSizes, $this->imageDir, Input::file('image'));
    }

    // Try and save the item
    if ($item->save())
    {
        // item saved, save the tags
        $this->tagRepo->saveTags($input['tags'], $item, $user);
    }

    // Return the item
    return $item;
}
```

I hope this is enough info, let me know if clarification is needed on anything.

Fankoo! :)

Comment: Can you assert that Request::isJson() is false? The most common cause for missing input is JSON input overwriting POST data or vice-versa.

Comment: I have no much time to dive in the problem, but you can use a rest client to test if the problem is with client or server side. I use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this: `headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }` ?

It should be `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }`

If Laravel doesn't see the Content-Type as application/json, it won't properly grab your json post.

Comment: btw, your paste link is broken.

Comment: Well, it's because he's trying `multipart/form-data` with `boundary`. Nothing else.